# Dom loaded Time after specifc ajax Event

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance

Need to capture the time taken to load a DOM Content for a specific ajax Event,

Need to be generalised like after clicking some action I need to capture the end time of DOM got loaded. I can capture the last Ajax Success time, but there might be some delay to display in screen after ajax got success method due to some processing can happen in success method.

Regards
**Krishna Kumar S**

Answer (score 0):

You can ajax events for your goal.

To capture time when ajax call starts, use `.ajaxStart()`.

To capture time when your `dom` get loaded use `.ajaxComplete()`.

You can find more info at [ajax Events](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)

Hope this help.

Comment: I am using .ajaxStop Event to capture the end Time, but will tat be my DOM loaded time ?Typically I want to capture the time last line of the ajax Call. Ajax Stop and completes capture when the success or event method got triggered right ??

Comment: To capture time of last line you should use ajaxComplete() which will fire after success: callback. .ajaxStop() event will fire after all ajax requests complete. Do you have single ajax call or multiple? You want the duration of each ajax call right?

Comment: I am having many ajax calls. if my  success function has less work to do, it will execute "Success" - > Complete -> Stop else Complete -> Stop -> Success last line

Comment: If your end goal it to capture duration of ajax call, you should not do like that you mentioned above. Be consistent across all the call. No matter you have less or more code in success callback.

Comment: My Goal is to capture the time take from end to end process starting from any transaction till it completes. ajax success function someting like it got values from server to Client, it doesn't mean it has completed it process right ?

Comment: Yes dear. You will observe that it will start when ajax call begin and ends when it completes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79760/discussion-between-krishna-and-simple-man).

Comment: What else you want to dicuss?